# C++ auto keyword for flexibility

Tags: c++, c++11, auto

Is it an good idea to use `auto` as much as possible so changing data types in your code is more flexible? Like if you use a bunch of range-based for loops would it be efficient to always use auto so you never have to go back and change the data type the for loop?

Comment: Definitely Yes: https://herbsutter.com/2013/08/12/gotw-94-solution-aaa-style-almost-always-auto/

Comment: Herb says yes, I agree for most cases (including range based for or lambdas). I'm not fully convinced about the 'always' part though. Especially if the type is not obvious, making it explicit makes the code imho easier to read and don't forget that redundancy can also catch errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, yes. See this for details [AAA](https://herbsutter.com/2013/08/12/gotw-94-solution-aaa-style-almost-always-auto/). However please be aware of some cases like this:

```
int x = 4;
int& ref = x;
auto y = ref;
```

`y` now is `int` not `int&`

```
const int x = 5;
auto y = x;
```

`y` is `int` not `const int`;

Comment: Can you provide examples of how those cases would be create undesirable outcomes?

Comment: I just wanted to emphasize that you may think that auto will get exactly the type with its & or const. it is not. So the first example will make a deep copy not just copying the reference.

Comment: @HumamHelfawi Well, it's exactly the behaviour I would expect, seeing as though you can write `auto&`.

Comment: @CoffeeandCode Yes exactly.. I just see it worth to mention